# Finding the parent elements based on child events

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, dom

I have an unordered list which I am using an a left navigation, each of the list items are links to different pages and this is collapsible and expandable.

I am using the below scripts in [fidddle](http://jsfiddle.net/balasivagnanam/ymgpvh0n/),

HTML:

```
<ul class="navi-list">
    <li class="no-subitem">
        <a class="current">Overview</a>
         <span class="navi-current"></span>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a class="has-subitem">
            <i class="fa fa-caret-right fw"> </i> Policies & Procedures 
        </a>
        <ul class="submenu">
            <li>
                <a href="#"> Documents & Resources </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#"> Upcoming Events </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#"> News </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#"> Announcements </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a class="has-subitem">
            <i class="fa fa-caret-right fw"> </i> Feeds & Discussions 
        </a>
        <ul class="submenu">
            <li>
                <a href="#"> Blog & Podcasts </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#"> Photos & Videos </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a class="has-subitem">
            <i class="fa fa-caret-right fw"> </i> About Us 
        </a>
        <ul class="submenu">
            <li>
                <a href="#"> FAQs </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#"> Contact Us </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Javascript:

```
$(".has-subitem").next(".submenu").hide();
/*    
    if($(".submenu > li > a").find("current")){
        var $here = $('this').parents().eq(1); 
        $('.submenu').show();
    }
*/
$(document).on("click", ".has-subitem", function () {
    $(this).next(".submenu").slideToggle();
    $(this).find('i').toggleClass("fa-caret-right fa-caret-down");
});
```

Now when I go to any of the internal links(which are seperate landing pages with an additional class current appended to the items), I would like to have that particular list open with others closed. Not sure how to achieve it.

I tried the commented code inside the fiddle. But it is opening up all the items instead of the currently active one.

After clicking the link, the new landing page navigation menu will have this,

```
<ul class="navi-list">
                            <li class="no-subitem">
                                <a href="hr-page.html">Overview</a>

                            </li>
                            <li><a class="has-subitem"><i class="fa fa-caret-right fw"> </i> Policies & Procedures </a>
                                <ul class="submenu">
                                    <li ><a class="current" href="#"> Documents & Resources </a>
                                    <span class="navi-current"></span>
                                    </li>
                                    <li><a href="#"> Upcoming Events </a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#"> News </a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#"> Announcements </a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                            <li><a class="has-subitem"><i class="fa fa-caret-right fw"> </i> Feeds & Discussions </a>
                                <ul class="submenu">
                                    <li><a href="#"> Blog & Podcasts </a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#"> Photos & Videos </a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                            <li><a class="has-subitem"><i class="fa fa-caret-right fw"> </i> About Us </a>
                                <ul class="submenu">
                                    <li><a href="#"> FAQs </a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#"> Contact Us </a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
```

As you could see, I need to find that current and make that submenu alone expanded while closing the others.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You need to find select `submenu` from other list hide them using `.slideUp()`:

```
$(document).on("click",".has-subitem",function(){
        $('.submenu').not($(this).next()).toggleClass("fa-caret-right fa-caret-down").slideUp();
        $(this).next(".submenu").slideToggle();
        $(this).find('i').toggleClass("fa-caret-right fa-caret-down");
    });
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/neLzv5La/)**

Comment: thanks for your time. But my case is, I am landing in a different page when the link is clicked, so I will have a "current" class added to the one clicked, so I need to find this and collapse that submenu alone

Comment: `$('.current').next().slideUp()`

Comment: not working.. have updated the new html for the landing page after clicking the link